# TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rename columns from an excel file in pandas but I'm getting the error in the title. The error is coming from line 18 or the # Rename Columns section. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the excel file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel("Marginal CPA data - NOV.xlsx")

# Delete the bottom row
df = df[:-1]

# Filter the column labeled "Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC" to keep only rows with value "NonBrand"
df = df[df["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC"] == "NonBrand"]

# Make a pivot table
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Media Cost", "CAFE Approvals"], 
                              index=["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC", "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC", "Day"], 
                              columns=["CDJ"], aggfunc="sum")

# Remove subtotals and repeat all item labels
pivot_table = pivot_table.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
pivot_table = pivot_table.rename_axis(None, axis=0)

# Copy and paste as values the pivot table into a new tab
df_pivot = pivot_table.copy()

# Rename columns
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns={("Media Cost", "CPA"): "CPA Spend", ("Media Cost", "Non CPA"): "CDJ Spend"})
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns={("CAFE Approvals", "CPA"): "CPA Approvals", ("CAFE Approvals", "Non CPA"): "CDJ Approvals"})
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Not having sample data makes it hard to solve but I believe your code should be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Marginal CPA data - NOV.xlsx")

df = df[:-1]

df = df[df["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC"] == "NonBrand"]

pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Media Cost", "CAFE Approvals"], 
                              index=["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC", "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC", "Day"], 
                              columns=["CDJ"], aggfunc="sum")

pivot_table = pivot_table.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
pivot_table = pivot_table.rename_axis(None, axis=0)

df_pivot = pivot_table.copy()

# Reset the column index to a single level
df_pivot.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in df_pivot.columns]

# Rename columns
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns={"Media Cost_CPA": "CPA Spend", "Media Cost_Non CPA": "CDJ Spend",
                                     "CAFE Approvals_CPA": "CPA Approvals", "CAFE Approvals_Non CPA": "CDJ Approvals"})
```

Comment: Hi @serge, here's a sample of the data:

Comment: Post it in your question. Doesn't show here.